# Opening an image in python with matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I am trying to open an image in python with matplotlib using this code:

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img=cv2.imread('d:\google.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

there is an image in d:\ which is google logo.

after that I am trying to run the code and I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/�����/PycharmProjects/untitled4/h.py", line 2, in <module>
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 71, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends import pylab_setup
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
line for line in traceback.format_stack()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 18, in <genexpr>
if not line.startswith('  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please help :)

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Comment: Yes, thank you :) the problem was that my saving path of the Python projects contains my username which is not in the english alphabet, and the computer found it hard to decode it. so the solution is choosing a path that contains only the English letters

Answer (score 0):

You code works for me.

Looking at your stack trace, the error is happening within the `matplotlib` package.

You should re-install your package, and see if the error goes away.

Try:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall matplotlib
```